# Ajax and PHP with a while loop issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a ajax that needs to return some values, but if I use a `while()` to get all the result from my db, the return is "nothing". Where am I making mistake?

My Ajax script is posted below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  function addmsg(type, msg) {
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
    // Your count variable
    var count = obj.count;
    // Your not variable
    var not = obj.not;
    $('#msg_count').html(count);
    $('#notification').html(not);

  }

  function waitForMsg() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "notification/select.php",
      cache: false,
      timeout: 50000,

      success: function(data) {
        addmsg("new", data);
        setTimeout(
          waitForMsg,
          1000
        );
      },
      error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        addmsg("error", textStatus + " (" + errorThrown + ")");
        setTimeout(
          waitForMsg,
          15000);
      }
    });
  };

  $(document).ready(function() {

    waitForMsg();

  });
</script>
```

My php script is posted below:

```
 $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * from notification where tousername='$tousername' and isread = 0");

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     $count = $result - > num_rows;
     $not = $row['notification_msg'];
     $res = [];
     $res['count'] = $count;
     $res['not'] = $not;
 }
 echo json_encode($res);
```

Comment: Does it literally return "nothing" (<-- this is a string), is the server not sending a response or does the server return nothing (<-- this is not a string)?

Comment: Its not returning anything. No errors too

Answer (score 4):

You are overwriting your results variable in the loop:

```
while (...) {
  ...
  $res=[];
  ...
}
```

You probably want something like:

```
$res['count'] = $result->num_rows;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $res[]['not'] = $row['notification_msg'];
}
echo json_encode($res);
```

Comment: Its not returning anything.

Comment: @SanjuMenon Where does `$tousername` come from, do you get any results when you open `notification/select.php` directly in the browser?

Comment: it comes from the database. and iam comparing its with the logged in user.

Comment: @SanjuMenon You should add that code and tell us what happens when you open `notification/select.php` in the browser.

Comment: Yes iam getting the proper output in select.php. This is the result...{"count":3,"0":{"not":"New Intender details entered 1"},"1":{"not":"New Intender details entered 2"},"2":{"not":"New Intender details entered 3"}}

Comment: @SanjuMenon Perhaps jQuery has already parsed the json automatically. If you do `console.log(data)` in your `success` function, what do you see? The results, and as a string or as an object? If you add `dataType: 'json'` to your ajax call, the json will get parsed automatically and you can remove the `jQuery.parseJSON` line from your function.

Comment: Yes, i did rewrote some code and its working fine now. How will show the value of 'count' and 'not'?       $('#msg_count').html(count);
         $('#notification').html(not);

Comment: @SanjuMenon You should be able to get the `count` like that, the `not` key will contain an array.

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite your value with same index. you can write this.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$count = $result->num_rows;
$not=$row['notification_msg'];
$res=[];
$res['count'][] = $count;
$res['not'][] = $not; 
}

Or

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$count = $result->num_rows;
$not=$row['notification_msg'];
$res=[];
$res[]['count'] = $count;
$res[]['not'] = $not; 
}

echo json_encode($res);
```

die();

Write your js `addmsg()` function.

```
function addmsg(type, msg) {
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
    // Your count variable
    for(prop in obj){
      var count = obj[prop][count];
      var not = obj[prop][not];
       $('#msg_count').html(count);
       $('#notification').html(not);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Do i need to change anything in the ajax script? like for example..adding an each..

Comment: iam sorry, its not returning anything. just blank. just seeing if i have made mistake

Comment: Basically iam doing a notification system like fb does. Its shows the count of unread messages. If we click the count, its shows the unread messages

Comment: Write die() function end of your echo json_encode($res);

Answer (score -1):

re-write your script

```
function waitForMsg(){
$.get("notification/select.php",function(callback){
console.log(callback); // here is your data in callback variabel you can in in console log
})
}
```

Replce this code with your php script.

```
 $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * from notification where tousername='$tousername' and isread = 0");

       $res['count'] = $result->num_rows;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      $res[]['not'] = $row['notification_msg'];
    }
    echo json_encode($res);
```

Comment: And what about my ajax script? Do i need to change anything?

Comment: Yes url is fine. But do i need to add $.each in the ajax to accomodate the while loop?

Comment: As of now my ajax script is written not to handle a loop. Am i correct?Am very new to ajax.

Comment: yes your script is ok.. but you can use $.get("notification/select.php",function(callback){  "you can looping callback variable here in javascript"})

Comment: Did you just literally copy my answer but without the explanation?